# Confusion about const syntax

Tags: c, function, pointers, constants

I'm having some trouble reading a line in a program that looks like this:

```
char* const *(*next) ();
```

I think `next` is a pointer to a function returning a pointer to a `const` pointer to a `char`, but I'm still a bit confused.  If someone could answer this ASAP that would be great!

Comment: It can help reading the signature right to left. Especially with "strange" pointers as this.

Answer (score 5):

**[cdecl](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=char*%20const%20*%28*next%29%20%28%29;)** can help you understand the more complicated declarations in C.

Comment: Give a man a fishing pole and he can read the most horrendously complicated type declarations conceivable.

Answer (score 2):

`char* const* (*next) ();`

You are declaring a function pointer called `next` that returns a `char* const*` (pointer to a `char* const`). You were right (:

Usage :

`char* const* ret = next();` or `char* const* ret = (*next)();`

Comment: takes an unspecified number of arguments; not "no arguments"